# AWS AppSync using wrong Iam role

Tags: ios, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-appsync

I am using services including dynamodb and s3 with ios for custom sign in user pools that is in use by a federated identity to give roles for authenticated and unauthenticated users. That works perfectly.

Then when I use AWS AppSync, I am just performing a Mutation and I get an error saying Unable to assume role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/xxxxxxxxx . This arn:aws:iam:xxx/xxx role that is trying to be used by AppSync is not the one I want to be used and the iam role is different from the role that DynamoDb and s3 are using for some reason even though I am not changing any cognitoid being used in the code. Please see below for some sample code.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// CognitoIdentityUserPoolId is the id of the federated identity from console. works fine with all services except for AppSync by wrong Iam role being chosen
  let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: nil)

  let userPoolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId, clientSecret: CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientSecret, poolId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolId)

  AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: userPoolConfiguration, forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)

  pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)

  let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolId, identityProviderManager:pool)

  let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

  AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

  pool?.delegate = self

  return true 
}
// In SampleViewController
  // after user signs in
  let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(url: AppSyncEndpointURL, serviceRegion: CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion, userPoolsAuthProvider: self)

  // Initialize the AWS AppSync client
  self.appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: appSyncConfig)

  // Set id as the cache key for objects
  self.appSyncClient?.apolloClient?.cacheKeyForObject = { $0["id"] }

// later on in the file....
extension SampleViewController: AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider{
  func getLatestAuthToken() -> String {
    return (myUserSess?.idToken?.tokenString)!
  }
}
```

Any help/reason why AWS AppSync is trying to use the wrong Iam name?

Answer (score 4):

Where are you getting that message? In the console when using the queries page or on the client? If it's in the console then the issue is probably with the IAM role for your Data Source and might make sense to recreate it or ensure you have the following trust policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "appsync.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

If it's on the client then the error might be when you're either initializing the Cognito Identity provider or the AppSync constructor.

Comment: I am getting the message on the client side. The source of the error is AWSAppSync.GraphQLResult<xx.xxx.Data>.Source.server. The data source is a dynamodb table and the Iam role that I use to access DynamoDb has full access and works when not through AppSync to read and write from client side. The problem is that the wrong Iam role is trying to be assumed for AppSync for some reason, do you know why that is? I just added the data source on AppSync console for the Mutation to be the table to which I created manually on DynamoDB console.

Comment: @Rekd then the issue is with the Cognito Role that is being granted to the client. Start by looking at the IAM policy on that role to ensure it has access to your AppSync endpoint (maybe temporarily open it up then restrict it if that works). If that's not the issue then it's the order/syntax in which you're calling Cognito.

Comment: I added the permissions to the auth role I have seen on posts with sts:assumerole and appsync:graphql but the role I am adding to is not trying to be assumed for some reason. I do not think that the cognitoid and userpoolid on the client is bad as clients can assume that auth role to access resources as specified in the policy for example DynamoDb read and write directly. Is there something I could do maybe on the AppSync console or creating other Iam roles to handle this as currently I have on AppSync console to allow my app userpool which seems not to assume the auth role for that userpool.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the role used with Appsync has ability to invoke Lambda function and the role associated with the resolver Lambda should have adequate permissions to access the database that you are trying to query.

Also, if there are any policies that are not applicable to AppSync, it will throw such an error.